# Returning an arbitrary row from a multidimensional array (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, row

I am working with a 5 dimensional array that is 5x5x5x5x5 in python.

How can I make a function that

- will take an integer i (1<=i<=5) for which dimension to iterate through, and a list of the other 4 dimensions [a,b,c,d] to be locked in
- return a 1-dimensional list of length 5

for example:

>>>bb = (5 dimensional array)

>>>rowExtract(3, [2,3,0,2], bb)

*[ bb[2][3][i][0][2] for i in range(5)] returns*

The 3 is for the 3rd dimension, and the 2,3,0,2 signifies the other dimensions

I could do it by hard coding 5 different scenarios, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way using loops.

```
def extract_row(row, arr, bb):
  N = len(arr) + 1

  pre_mat = bb
  for i in range(row):
    pre_mat = pre_mat[arr[i]]

  ans = [] 
  for i in range(N):
    mat = pre_mat[i]
    for j in range(row + 1, N):
      mat = mat[arr[j - 1]]

    ans.append(mat)

  return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way. So something like this

```
def extractRow(row, arr, bb):
    if row == 0:
        return [bb[i][arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]] for i in range(5)]
    elif row == 1:
        return [bb[arr[0]][i][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]] for i in range(5)]
    ...
```

Comment: Hmmm, I agree. I haven't seen a problem like this anywhere else on the internet. It seems like Python doesn't support such a specific issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution uses an iterator to generate the sequence of indices.  The "missing" dimension can be inserted into `arr`, and each time through the generator's loop it fills that index with the next value.  Each time the generator yields, it produces a 5-element array containing the indices needed to extract the next value from `bb`.  Then you can pick the element you want from `bb`.

```
def extract_row(row, bb, arr):
    retval = []
    for a0, a1, a2, a3, a4 in iter_indices(row, arr):
        retval.append(bb[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4])
    return retval

def iter_indices(row, arr):
    arr.insert(row, None)
    for i in range(5):
        arr[row] = i
        yield arr

# TEST CODE FOLLOWS
g = 0
def deepen(b, n):
    global g
    if n == 1:
        b.append(g)
        b.append(g+1)
        b.append(g+2)
        b.append(g+3)
        b.append(g+4)
        g += 5
        return b
    for m in range(5):
        b.append(deepen([], n-1))
    return b

a = []
deepen(a, 5)

# Run it using the test matrix a
print(extract_row(1, a, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(a[1][0][2][3][4], a[1][1][2][3][4], a[1][2][2][3][4], a[1][3][2][3][4], a[1][4][2][3][4])


Output is:
[694, 819, 944, 1069, 1194]
694 819 944 1069 1194
```